# Read a Google Sheet with Python using API Key instead of OAuth Client ID [Python]

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

While there are several useful articles on how to use OAuth Client IDs to generate credentials needed for reading and writing to Google Sheets, I have been unable to make sense of how one would use the alternative API Key (token) in such a context.

I've blindly attempted to simply pass the token string into `gspread.authorize(TOKEN)` but, not surprisingly, received an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'access_token'`

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, the Google Sheet api can use Api key.
The main difference between Api key and OAuth 2.0 is that
the Api key can only access public data.

For REST http request, You can append the query parameter key=yourAPIKey to all request URLs.

For python, see the google-api-python-client library's reference.
The build() function has a parameter named developerKey.
I wrote a simple example which is modified from the offical quickstart.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery


def main(key=None):
    discoveryUrl ='https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'
    service = discovery.build(
        'sheets',
        'v4',
        http=httplib2.Http(),
        discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl,
        developerKey=key)

    spreadsheetId = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
    rangeName = 'Class Data!A2:E'
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        print('Name, Major:')
        for row in values:
            # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[4]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv

    if len(argv) == 2:
        main(key=argv[1])
    else:
        main()
```

Some useful offical links.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/api-keys

However，most popular third library based on offical library does not expose the developerKey parameter.

Answer (score -2):

Every [method in the Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/) need authorization using the OAuth. Refer to [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) to get started.

Comment: Okay, I can accept that, I'm being a baby about needing to include a JSON file with my script in the case of using OAuth...BUT! Would you happen to know the use of the "API Key" authorization option then? What is it used for if not to authenticate access to a user, much like the tokens used by, for instance, the Slack and Dropbox APIs?



I started exploring APIs through this example under the `Basic Usage > Sending A Message` sections of [this Git example for Slack](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient)...trying to draw parallels...?